# Is there a way to make a leaderboard with several json files?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, leaderboard

in my current command, I get the leaderboard from a single json file called **users.json** that stores several XP from multiple users:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def top(ctx):

    with open('profile/users.json', 'r') as fp:
        users = json.load(fp)
        lb = [(member, users[member.id].get('xp')) for member in ctx.message.server.members if member.id in users]
        lb.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

However, I changed the command, and had each person store their XP in a separate json file:
What was once **'profile/users.json'** became several **'profile/{}.json'.format(ctx.message.author.id)**
Now inside the **profile** folder, there are several json files of each user, with their respective xp, instead of a single json file.
I would like a way to do a leaderboard using multiple json files at once, rather than just one, using my code, what can I do?
Complete answers please, if you need more data, please tell me that and I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening and loading one file, iterate over all the filenames in the `profile` directory. Load each one and store it in a list for later.

```
import glob
import json    

filenames_of_all_users = glob.glob("profile/*.json")
users = []
for filename in filenames_of_all_users:
    with open(filename) as file:
        users.append(json.load(file))

users.sort(key=lambda user: user["xp"], reverse=True)

output = ["'''"]
for i, user in enumerate(users, 1):
    output.append(f"{i}. {user['name']}: {user['xp']} XP")
    if i == 20:
        break
output.append("'''")
result = "\n".join(output)
print(result)
```

I've made a couple of other changes here, which aren't essential to the solution, but which are more idiomatic and/or efficient:

- using `enumerate` instead of manually keeping track of the index in the for loop
- using `join()` instead of concatenating strings with +=